# run time error 35788. An Error occurred in a call to the Windows Date & time picker control

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel 2007 sheet with VBA user forms to get data from access. Everything works fine. Data also gets populated over VBA form but when i click on any Multi-page tab then it throws the following error (though i can see values were loaded successfully):

> Run time error 35788. An Error occurred in a call to the Windows Date & time picker control

How can I fix this?

Note: I have used Me.Multipage.Value = 0 or 1 as per page index before code executes for multipage tab. e.g. before 2nd page code execution i set index as 1.

When i click over user form field name on debugging then it highlight as 12:00:00 AM & access field name shows correct date value.

Answer (score 3):

Finally i got this working with little more head beating. I added `Me.Multipage1.Value = 0` in the last of code & it started working. Though i think it should not have anything with error i received above but i got this working. Anyhow. Thanks.

May be this helps someone else running with same trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The date time picker needs to be shown before the added value, so if you have a multi-page user form, you need to show the page containing the date time picker first.